# Are there any Magento Code Release Notes?

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, documentation

I have been looking for some kind of **code** release notes. I have browsed through the released notes information and through all the versions trying to find any kind of clear statement where they say which files have added, edited or deleted.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/bk-release-notes.html

The purpose of this is that I have Custom Modules which I need to modify in order to get them working for the Magento version that I need and the release notes are useful but it does take time to have a look at each change in an attempt to get the right code written in the modules.

In my case I'm trying to go from 2.1.9 to 2.2.5.

As I said, is there anywhere I could search? If there isn't, how do you guys do it? Just looking at the error logs and the release notes and working with all of it? Thank you for your time.

Comment: you can check file diff here  https://github.com/magento/magento2/releases   tagwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento does not provide a record of which files have been changed in each release. It just provides release notes which provided highlights of what has changed and who changed it:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.5CE.html

To find this out for yourself, you would need to diff the files of one version with another.

Comment: I do know about these files, but as you say, they just provide highlights. Anyway, thanks.